# Команды не загружаются - discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Есть проблема - не работают команды. Причем в консоли, данный код, бот успешно загружает. Но при вводе команд, прописанных в коде - ответа нет. Прошу помочь мне с данным недоразумением.

Заранее спасибо!

Команд loader:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for file in os.listdir("cogs"):
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            extension = file[:-3]
            try:
                bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
                print(f"Loaded extension '{extension}'")
            except Exception as e:
                exception = f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}"
                print(f"Failed to load extension {extension}\n{exception}")
```

Сам код с командой

```py
import json
import os
import sys
import pymysql.cursors
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

db = pymysql.connect(host='',
                     port=25060,
                     user='bot',
                     password='',
                     database='bot',
                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

with db.cursor() as cursor:
    # Read a single record
    sql = ("select `id` from `owners`")
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

with db.cursor() as cursor:
    # Read a single record
    sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `blacklisted`"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    bl = cursor.fetchall()

class owner(commands.Cog, name="owner"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name="shutdown")
    async def shutdown(self, context, message):
        if context.message.author.id:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                description="сдох. покеда :wave:",
                color=0x42F56C
            )
            await context.send(embed=embed)
            await self.bot.close()
            await message.channel.send('ок')
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Ошибка!",
                description="У вас недостаточно прав для выполнения данной команды",
                color=0xE02B2B
            )
            await context.send(embed=embed)
            await message.channel.send('ok')
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(owner(bot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [`bot.load_extension()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension)
В скобках пишите путь к файлу:

```
bot.load_extension('cogs.help')#cogs - папка, help - название файла с командой
```

И теперь вам не надо вот этого:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for file in os.listdir("cogs"):
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            extension = file[:-3]
            try:
                bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
                print(f"Loaded extension '{extension}'")
            except Exception as e:
                exception = f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}"
                print(f"Failed to load extension {extension}\n{exception}")
```